# How do I output the full URL for an entry, including the category paths?

Tags: categories, url-title, child-categories

I'm try to output an Entry URL like this, which includes the Category URL Titles:

```
/products/category/sub-category/sub-sub-category/entry-url-title
```

But I can't work out how to achieve this.
Any ideas anyone?

**EDIT**

This is the code I have so far, but I don't know how to inject the category URLs into the link:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products"}
    <a href="/products/*** category urls to go here ***/{url_title}">{title}</a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: You're going to need to post some of your template code to be able to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

What version of EE are you using?
In EE2 there is nothing native out of the box that does this.
But this will help you do it:

[http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation)

Using GWCode Categories your template code should look something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products"}

<a href="/products
   {exp:gwcode_categories channel="{channel_short_name}"
                          entry_id="{entry_id}"
                          max_depth="3"
                          style="linear"
   }
   /{cat_url_title}
   {/exp:gwcode_categories}

/{url_title}">{title}</a>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I'm using EE3. I've found that Category Construct by Buzzing Pixel is quite good - but it seems like a lot of work to generate something which I would have expected to work natively in EE. https://buzzingpixel.com/software/category-construct